# error: use of undeclared identifier 'localhost'

Tags: qt, tcpclient

I am implementing a TCP Client application. I am trying following line of code:

```
socket->connectToHost (localhost, 1234);
```

I am getting the error shown below:

> error: use of undeclared identifier 'localhost'

I understand it doesn't have the correct header included. Which header contains "localhost"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localhost` is a variable name ("identifier").  You probably meant `connectToHost("localhost", 1234);`.

And while drilling further into [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qhostaddress.html#SpecialAddress-enum), it seems that `SpecialAddress::LocalHost` is a thing, too, defined next to the socket class.  So something like this should also work:

```cpp
auto localhost = QHostAddress(QSpecialAddress::LocalHost);
socket->connectToHost(localhost, 1234);
```